# What is a Designated Initializer?

Tags: c++, c++20, designated-initializer

I wish to understand what designated initializers provide that is different to direct initialization.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Subject{

    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

};

int main()
{ 
    Subject subject_d{.x = 1, .y = 2, .z= 3};
    Subject subject_c{1, 2, 3};

    return 0;
}
```

How can we decorticate these two lines? For the meticulous ones, what is the difference?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica i suspect this is a literal 'translation' of the french verb 'décortiquer' for which one of the meanings is to thoroughly analyze something

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica if like french word -> peel / hull ^^ And in that context "how to understand"

Comment: "*for the meticulous ones*" ^^

Comment: @rekkalmd: I don't understand the question. You start by saying that you understand the difference, but then you ask what the difference is.

Comment: Interesting. Usually a quick web search doesn't fail me so miserably. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: You have solved everything, I appreciate !

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, i'm sorry ! i'm new to this term (Designated Initializer), so i'm asking to know why it is added, is there a difference with calling normally `Subject subject_c{1, 2, 3};` ?

Comment: @rekkalmd It lets you omit initializers for any of the fields. `Subject subject_c{...};` only lets you omit N last fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the example you posted, there's absolutely no difference in terms of the behavior. The aggregate is initialized to hold the same three values. In terms of readability, an argument can be made that the designated initializer version is more explicit in terms of what is happening. It can also be used to serve a documentation purpose. The intended meaning of each initializer (assuming we named the members well) is written right next to it.

Beyond explicit-ness in initialization. Designated initializers also play nice with other C++ features. Consider instead.

```
struct Subject{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
};
```

You could write

```
Subject const s { .y = 2 };
```

We go with the default value for all fields except `y`. And the variable `s` is const, because we don't want it to change. It's good in terms of const correctness.

You can achieve a similar effect without designated initializers, but it would involve a fair more boiler-plate if we want `s` to remain const, and would arguably not be as terse and clear. That's in a nut-shell why they are nice to have in the language.

Answer (score 3):

that line :

> ```
> Subject subject_d{.x = 1, .y = 2, .z= 3};
> ```

it will not anymore compile if you rename at least one of the fields or change their order, so that form is 'secure'

but

> ```
> Subject subject_c{1, 2, 3};
> ```

does not assumption on the name of the fields, so if you exchange their order the initialization of each fields will not be the same but silentely

Answer (score 2):

The two lines are semantically equivalent. One of the two is more explicit, which can lead to fewer software errors.